# Project Order in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In Visual Studio 2008, what determines the order in which projects appear within a solution folder? It's not alphabetical order, nor is it build order.

I cannot find any way of altering the order in which projects are being listed. I've tried removing my *.suo* file, as well as moving things about in the *.sln* file. Neither had any effect.

**How can I change the order in which my projects are being displayed?**

Comment: I have even worse situation. From time to time, VS 2008 decides to re-order my projects ... It awful, just when I used to "its order", it decides to changed and in a solution with more than 100 project, it's a nightmare finding anything!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a feedback Request already placed at Connect.Microsoft.com so, you will have to wait for the permanent solution.

[http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/468874/solution-explorer-project-sort-order](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621134819/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/468874/solution-explorer-project-sort-order) (replaced with Wayback Machine link as original was removed)

Temporary workarounds are available but not good enough I feel. One of them is:

> Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a project, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without changing the name. This temporarily sorts the projects within that folder.

(As per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/79d46a69-386e-4ad8-b9cb-b00d4252495b/?prof=required )

Or use http://solutionsorter.codeplex.com/ to alter SLN for permanent fix *if your solution folders are not nested* (it ate my solution)

But this will not work if you close and open the solution.

> If you use Resharper, you can press
>   the short cut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to find out
>   files in solution and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to
>   find out methods in the file.

Comment: AFAIK it's fixed in VS2010, I expect that there won't be a permanent solution for VS2008.

Comment: @Benjol define "fixed"? always sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately VS2010 forces projects to be alphabetically sorted.

Perhaps renaming the projects by adding a numerical prefix (01, 02, 03, etc) to achieve the desired order is the only workaround, although not ideal either.

Answer (score 7):

Take file .sln in any text editor.
Order the parts
"
 Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "etc..."
 ...
 EndProject

in any order you want.
Save it.
That's all.
Next time you will open this solution the projects will be in THAT order.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect in VS2010 (original question was about VS2008, but I just tried this in vain hopes it would work)

Answer (score 4):

Hacky alternative: Copy out the section with these lines into a text file.

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "etc..."
EndProject
```

Use this F# script to sort it alphabetically (changing file path as required):

```
open System.IO

let readlines p = File.ReadAllLines(p)
let writelines p lines = File.WriteAllLines(p, lines)

let startpos = @"Project(""{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"") = """.Length
let getProj (s:string) = s.Substring(startpos, s.IndexOf('"', startpos) - startpos)

let path = @"C:\Temp\sln.txt"
path |> readlines
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> s.StartsWith("Project"))
    |> Array.map (fun s -> (getProj(s), s))
    |> Array.sortBy fst
    |> Array.map snd
    |> Array.collect (fun s -> [|s;"EndProject"|])
    |> writelines path
```

*(If you've only got a few projects, just sort it by hand)*

Answer (score 2):

Per this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118705/835561

You can use Solution Folders to do your sorting without worrying about it affecting project dependencies. Not sure how well this works prior to 2013, but I came across this question looking for 2013 and thought this might help others in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The [dotnet sln add](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln) command reorder all projects in all folders in solution for me.

Simply add at least one project with the following command to your solution:

```
dotnet sln $Solution add --solution-folder $SolutionFolder $projectPath
```

Or without a solution folder:

```
dotnet sln $Solution add --in-root $projectPath
```