# Visual Studio: How to arrange the projects inside solution explorer by dependency

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

Is there any way to manually arrange the projects inside solution explorer of VS 2010+ based on the dependency (dependent project on higher level) ?

Answer (score 25):

No, but when I have a solution with a lot of projects that I want to convey this build flow, I do something that may suit your needs.

Because the Solution Explorer sorts things alphabetically, I put projects into "Solution Folders". I put a prefix on each project folder. So, I might name a folder **"A. Helper Assemblies"**. So, my solution looks like this:

*Solution*
   **A. Helper Assemblies**
      Project1.vsproj
      Project2.vsproj
   **B. Core Assemblies**
      ProjectX.vsproj
      ProjectY.vsproj
   **C. UI Assemblies**
      ProjectMoe.vsproj
      ProjectLarry.vsproj
      ProjectShemp.vsproj

This doesn't change any project dependencies, though. It's simply a manual effort to ensure that the project build order matches the folder structure.

For exact details on adding a Solution Folder, go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6c756s6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Love it, because this are virtual folders that will not appear in the explorer.

Comment: Just changed the URL. MSDN changed its URL schema - all URL-s are now "global" => the [vstudio/] part is gone.

Answer (score 5):

On top of using solution folders and solution folder prefixes, you can use prefixes on project folders too.

The trick is to add the project with a normal name, then rename it "select it and press f2" in solution explorer.

By renaming it after you've added it, you keep your assembly name/namespace the way it should be.  Also renaming it after means your project folder name doesn't change with the prefix.  So the below example, on disk, would be Thing.Core not 10_Thing.Core

- 05_Thing.Database
- 10_Thing.Core
- 15_Thing.Api
- 20_Thing.Api.Services
- 25_Thing.Data
- 30_Thing.Host
- 90_Thing.Test