# How to arrange projects order in Visual Studio's Solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

Is there a way that we can arrange the Projects order in Visual Studio's solution explorer based on project references instead of default alphabetical order.

For e.g, we see some default hierarchies of projects when we generate Code map (.dgml)

I tried searching, but could not find anything.

**Purpose:** *I need this feature in case someone looks an already developed solution with lots of projects for the first time.*

Answer (score 5):

Visual studio currently does not support that from what I've seen as well. There are some hacks our there like putting your projects into folders or manually editing the order in the SLN file but both are just that... Hacks.

[Organizing a Solution with folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6fatbd5(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Stackoverflow Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715221/visual-studio-how-to-arrange-the-projects-inside-solution-explorer-by-dependenc)

[Visual Studio Product Enhancement Vote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/7878282-custom-project-order-in-visual-studio-solution)

Comment: Wel this hack would work only when you already know the projects completely. I needed this feature in case someone looks an already developed solution with lots of projects for the first time.

Comment: I prefix all my stuff with a number to make it order the same way it is in my brain (cause I'm not a dictionary)....its a cludge and causes a few messy issues, but for the most part it works...