# Visual Studio 2012 Recent Projects List - Sort Order

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What's the sort order on the Recent Projects list of VS 2012? I will work on a solution, go to a different one and want to switch back and the item is 12th on the list. I can go in to the start page and change the order but it would be nice if VS did it itself.

It's acting as if there is no sort order.

TIA - Jeff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Order in Visual Studio Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244765/project-order-in-visual-studio-solution)

Comment: That link is for the order of the projects in a solution. I'm talking about the Recent Projects and Solutions under the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

By default Visual Studio sorts the recent projects list by the datetime of the last access in descending order.

So if you switch between 2 Projects, these will go to the top of the recent list.

I don't know exactly why your vs2012 installation behaves differently, but you may try following solutions:

### Solution 1:

---

You can try and clear the recent Project list by manipulating the Registry:

Navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectMRUList and delete all the entries you find.

### Solution 2:

---

Try a clean reinstall of vs2012 (including latest update 5)